# SQL Server Activity monitor & explain plan truncates the query

Tags: sql-server, ssms

- SQL Server Management Studio 17.2
- SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.6329.1)

I'm trying to track down a problematic query. I'm looking at the Activity monitor and when I try to view the whole query, it's truncated.

How do I configure SSMS to show the whole query?

[image: query is truncated]

Comment: It's about time you updated your SSMS to the latest version. And don't bother with the built-in tools, there are much better utilities and scripts for diagnosing performance issues.

Comment: ^ yes, please [don't use Activity Monitor](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/why-i-dont-use-sql-server-activity-monitor/), and there are [better tools for plan analysis](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer), too. Note that if you are pulling the XML from the plan cache, the data is _stored_ truncated, so there's no way for any tool or script to magically reconstruct the full text. Catch it in the act, tracking problematic queries using [OpenQueryStore](https://dbafromthecold.com/2017/08/19/query-store-functionality-in-earlier-versions-of-sql-server/) or a proper monitoring tool.

Comment: If you have already identified the expensive query  and just want to extract the text then you can use SQL profiler as well. It's in built in SSMS and can be accessed from Tools menu at the top.